# Pass local value as job parameter to a job while still using the JobParametersIncrementer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring-batch job that I start with JobOperator#startNextInstance(String) method:

```
@Autowired
private JobOperator jobOperator;

private startMyJob() {
    jobOperator.startNextInstance("myJob");
}
```

With this method, spring-batch automatically creates job parameters from a bean that implements the JobParametersIncrementer interface. My implementation adds some globally available status information like the current user and current time.

Now, I want to pass another job parameter to the job that is only available locally in the startMyJob() method. I have tried to use the JobOperator#start(String, String) method:

```
private startMyJob() {
    jobOperator.start("myJob", "localJobParam=someLocalValue");
}
```

However, now the JobParametersIncrementer is no longer called and the global parameter values are missing. I could obviously call the incrementor myself, mix all parameters into a single parameter string and pass this to the JobOperator#start(String, String) method:

```
@Autowired
private JobParametersIncrementer jobParametersIncrementer;

private startMyJob() {
    JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersIncrementer.getNext(null);
    // convert jobParameters to comma separated key=value pairs
    // add additional key=value pair with locally available data
    jobOperator.start("myJob", commaSeparatedKeyValuePairString);
}
```

This process results in rather long and cumbersome code, since the JobParameters class does not provide a direct way to get the comma separated key=value pair string.

Is there a better way to start a job where some job parameters are passed directly and some result from the JobIncrementer bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are not using the `JobLauncher` interface instead of `JobOperator`?
`JobLauncher.run()` use a `JobParameters` instead of comma-separated values.
Also `JobOperator` is a low-level interface as described in its javadoc.

> Low level interface for inspecting and controlling jobs with access
>   only to primitive and collection types. Suitable for a command-line
>   client (e.g. that launches a new process for each operation), or a
>   remote launcher like a JMX console.

Addiction:
Use a `JobParametersBuilder` to build up parameters then call `JobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters()`; in this way you remove all cumbersome code.

Comment: I can not under stand how using JobLauncher.run() will solve the issue. You will not know/use the last run.id so in case you call the job with the same local parameter you will get JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException or JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException

Answer (score 2):

I found no solution in the Spring Framework, so I implemented a custom JobOperator which delegates all the calls to a SimpleJobOperator, and simply declares a new method `startNextInstance(String jobName, String parameters)` that automatically use the jobParameterIncrementer if the job has one.

```
public class JobParametersJobOperator implements JobOperator, InitializingBean {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    private SimpleJobOperator delegate;


    private ListableJobLocator jobRegistry;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobParametersConverter jobParametersConverter = new DefaultJobParametersConverter();

    public Long startNextInstance(String jobName, String parameters) throws NoSuchJobException, JobParametersNotFoundException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        this.logger.info("Locating parameters for next instance of job with name=" + jobName);
        Job job = this.jobRegistry.getJob(jobName);
        List lastInstances = this.jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName, 0, 1);
        JobParametersIncrementer incrementer = job.getJobParametersIncrementer();
        JobParameters jobParameters = this.jobParametersConverter.getJobParameters(PropertiesConverter.stringToProperties(parameters));
        if(incrementer == null) {
            throw new JobParametersNotFoundException("No job parameters incrementer found for job=" + jobName);
        } else {
            jobParameters = incrementer.getNext(jobParameters);
            this.logger.info(String.format("Attempting to launch job with name=%s and parameters=%s", new Object[]{jobName, parameters}));
            try {
                return this.jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters).getId();
            } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException var7) {
                throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException(String.format("Illegal state (only happens on a race condition): %s with name=%s and parameters=%s", new Object[]{"job already running", jobName, parameters}), var7);
            } catch (JobRestartException var8) {
                throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException(String.format("Illegal state (only happens on a race condition): %s with name=%s and parameters=%s", new Object[]{"job not restartable", jobName, parameters}), var8);
            } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException var9) {
                throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException(String.format("Illegal state (only happens on a race condition): %s with name=%s and parameters=%s", new Object[]{"job instance already complete", jobName, parameters}), var9);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getExecutions(long l) throws NoSuchJobInstanceException {
        return delegate.getExecutions(l);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getJobInstances(String s, int i, int i1) throws NoSuchJobException {
        return delegate.getJobInstances(s, i, i1);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Long> getRunningExecutions(String s) throws NoSuchJobException {
        return delegate.getRunningExecutions(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameters(long l) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException {
        return delegate.getParameters(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Long start(String s, String s1) throws NoSuchJobException, JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        return delegate.start(s, s1);
    }

    @Override
    public Long restart(long l) throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, NoSuchJobExecutionException, NoSuchJobException, JobRestartException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        return delegate.restart(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Long startNextInstance(String s) throws NoSuchJobException, JobParametersNotFoundException, JobRestartException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, UnexpectedJobExecutionException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        return delegate.startNextInstance(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stop(long l) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException, JobExecutionNotRunningException {
        return delegate.stop(l);
    }

    @Override
    public String getSummary(long l) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException {
        return delegate.getSummary(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Long, String> getStepExecutionSummaries(long l) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException {
        return delegate.getStepExecutionSummaries(l);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getJobNames() {
        return delegate.getJobNames();
    }

    @Override
    public JobExecution abandon(long l) throws NoSuchJobExecutionException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException {
        return delegate.abandon(l);
    }

    public void setJobRegistry(ListableJobLocator jobRegistry) {
        this.jobRegistry = jobRegistry;
    }

    public void setJobExplorer(JobExplorer jobExplorer) {
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
    }

    public void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    public void setJobRepository(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        delegate = new SimpleJobOperator();
        delegate.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        delegate.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        delegate.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        delegate.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    }
}
```

And here is the configuration file:

```
<bean id="jobOperator" class="com.x.y.z.JobParametersJobOperator">
    <property name="jobExplorer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
</bean>
```

And it can be called like this:

```
public class Launcher {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Launcher.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, NoSuchJobException, JobParametersNotFoundException, JobInstanceAlreadyExistsException {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        JobParametersJobOperator operator = context.getBean(JobParametersJobOperator.class);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("schedule.date", args[0]).toJobParameters();
        for (String job: operator.getJobNames()) {
            operator.startNextInstance(job, PropertiesConverter.propertiesToString(jobParameters.toProperties()));
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this could be useful for someone.